# How Can I do Query Builder in my Laravel controller?

Tags: sql, laravel, controller, query-builder

I'm trying to create a dynamic chart and I want to do some query.

In My PhpMyAdmin I find the right syntax of my query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM organigrammes 
WHERE direction = 'CPLE' AND statut = 'CDI';
```

Now I want to put it in my controller but I have not found the right syntax.

For example:

```
 public function index(Request $request) {
     return view(
      'home',['NbreCDD' =>Organigramme::where('direction','DRH' and 'statut','CDI')->count());
 }
```

Need a help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  public function index(Request $request) {
    $NbreCDD = Organigramme::where('direction','=','DRH') 
                        ->where('statut','=','CDI')
                        ->count();
    return view('home',['NbreCDD' => $NbreCDD]); 
}
```

Comment: I always prefer to use `compact` when the variable name is the same as the variable name sent to the view, e.g. `return view('home', compact($NbreCDD));`

Comment: Many Thanks @Prashant Deshmukh but it's not working. Because, Instead of having 2 as result , I have 16 corresponding to the records of entries of my table organigramme

Comment: @SaliouMBALO then you should make sure your table entries because eloquent should give same result as query you mentioned.

Comment: @Prashant Deshmukh Thanks you very much. I did a mistake in the synthax you gave me. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks you for the Help.

Comment: @SaliouMBALO Please approve and upvote if it helped.